# Keep menu bar on top without position:fixed

Tags: html, css

[Here's a link to the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/j3rs8pty/) I have a nice menu bar at the top, but it won't stay as the user scrolls down. When I try to change the CSS to include `position:fixed` under the first `#cssmenu`, everything gets thrown out of whack.

Here's the code inside the snippet:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:'Abraham Lincoln';
    src: url(../fonts/Abraham-Lincoln/AbrahamLincoln.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family:'Ingleby';
    src: url(../fonts/Ingleby/Ingleby_regular);
}
body {
    font-family:'Ingleby';
    background-image: url(../Images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
h2.names {
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Abraham Lincoln';
}
h3.date {
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Abraham Lincoln';
    margin-top: -20px;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Abraham Lincoln';
}
p {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.background {
    width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
footer {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(59, 58, 76);
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
footer a {
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#map-canvas {
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 200px;
}

/* ------------ */

/*   NEW MENU   */

/* ------------ */
 #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li, #cssmenu span, #cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu {
    line-height: 1;
    background: #141414;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
    width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
    background: #141414;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 19px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
    float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
    text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
    float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a, #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a, #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    background: #070707;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
    z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
    *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #0fa1e0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
    font-size: 11px;
    filter: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
    background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul, #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #0c7fb0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
    background: #0a6d98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a, #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a, #cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a, #cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a, #cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a, #cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>

        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>

            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>

        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 <h2 class="names">Bob + Suzy</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>I absolutely love this webpage!</p>
<p>It is soooooo cool!</p>
```

Comment: `position:fixed` _is_ what you should use for what you want to achieve; if _“everything gets thrown out of whack”_ then that’s what you should fix. (And if you want our help with that, first of all be more specific as to what that means.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. Added `.before_content` class to give margin between menu and content.

```
#cssmenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.before_content { 
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:'Abraham Lincoln';
    src: url(../fonts/Abraham-Lincoln/AbrahamLincoln.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family:'Ingleby';
    src: url(../fonts/Ingleby/Ingleby_regular);
}
body {
    font-family:'Ingleby';
    background-image: url(../Images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
h2.names {
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Abraham Lincoln';
}
h3.date {
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Abraham Lincoln';
    margin-top: -20px;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Abraham Lincoln';
}
p {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.background {
    width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
footer {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(59, 58, 76);
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
footer a {
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#map-canvas {
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 200px;
}

/* ------------ */

/*   NEW MENU   */

/* ------------ */
 #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li, #cssmenu span, #cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu {
    line-height: 1;
    background: #141414;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
    width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
    background: #141414;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 19px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
    float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
    text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
    float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a, #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a, #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    background: #070707;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
    z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
    *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #0fa1e0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
    font-size: 11px;
    filter: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
    background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul, #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #0c7fb0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
    background: #0a6d98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a, #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a, #cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a, #cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a, #cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a, #cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.before_content { 
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>

        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>

            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>

        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="before_content"></div>
 <h2 class="names">Bob + Suzy</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>I absolutely love this webpage!</p>
<p>It is soooooo cool!</p>
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Does this roughly do what @michaeldziedzic's answer does, just adds padding to a new class instead of the `h2`?

Comment: That's right, I have added a new div instead of customizing `<h2>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the bottom of your CSS:

```
#cssmenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 75px; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/hLwh5wpr/